# Simulate failed transaction using StoreKitTest

Tags: swift, unit-testing, in-app-purchase, storekittest

I am trying to use StoreKitTest to simulate `.failed` transaction in my unit tests. For the test session I set:

```
testSession.failTransactionsEnabled = true
testSession.failureError = SKError.Code.unknown
```

after that I call:

```
testSession.buyProduct(productIdentifier: productIdentifier)
```

I assumed that
`func paymentQueue(_ queue: SKPaymentQueue, updatedTransactions transactions: [SKPaymentTransaction])` delegate method should be called with `transactionState` `failed`.Unfortunately the delegate method is not called, any ideas why?

I was able to simulate `purchased` transaction using StoreKitTest. I am using Xcode 12.0 beta 6.

Comment: Same problem here in my unit tests. Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: Unfortunately not. Though I haven't tested on the latest Xcode

Comment: Hello, did you try to call SKPaymentQueue.default().add(payment) instead of using the testSession ?